# i can't see my dynamic labels, but I know they are there

Tags: vba, dynamic, multipage

I have used some code from here to place some labels on a multipage.  I can tell after the 5th label is placed that something is happening because there is a break in the frame after the 5th iteration of the routine, but nothing is visible.

```
Sub pgSSRs()
    Dim MPg As MSForms.MultiPage
    Dim NewLabel As MSForms.Label
    Dim Listarray As Integer
    Dim labelCounter As Long

    Listarray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SSRs").Range("SSRs").Rows.Count

    'MsgBox (Listarray & " SSRs")
    'Top = 50

    For labelCounter = 1 To Listarray
        Set NewLabel = UserForm1.Controls.Add("forms.label.1", "Test" & labelCounter, True)
        With NewLabel
            .Visible = True
            .Caption = "Test" & labelCounter
            .Height = 30
            .Left = 700
            .Width = 50
            .Top = Top + 10 * labelCounter
            MsgBox (.Top & " iteration")
        End With
    Next

    'MsgBox ("this is the SSR Page!")

End Sub
```

Can anyone provide assistance in helping me see these labels?  Eventually I want to make each label read from a cell on a worksheet, but having trouble with the simple stuff...

Answer (score 0):

You need to **Enable** the labels:

`.Enabled = True`

Then you should show it at the end?

`UserForm1.Show`

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unclear exactly what you want to do, but this worked for me (it added labels to the first page of the multi-page control)

You have to add the labels directly to the "page" contained by the control, and not add them to the "root" level of the userform itself.

```
Sub pgSSRs()

    Dim MPg As MSForms.MultiPage
    Dim NewLabel As MSForms.Label
    Dim Listarray As Integer
    Dim labelCounter As Long

    Listarray = 5 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SSRs").Range("SSRs").Rows.Count

    Set MPg = UserForm1.MultiPage1

    For labelCounter = 1 To Listarray
        'add labels to first page
        Set NewLabel = MPg.Pages(0).Controls.Add("forms.label.1", "Test" & labelCounter, True)
        With NewLabel
            .Visible = True
            .Caption = "Test" & labelCounter
            .Height = 30
            .Left = 10
            .Width = 50
            .Top = 20 + (10 * labelCounter)
            Debug.Print .Top & " iteration"
        End With
    Next

    UserForm1.Show

    'MsgBox ("this is the SSR Page!")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I eventually stopped trying to use multipage and went to multiple user forms.  I still had trouble for quite awhile until I realized that for new label I needed to point to the frame and not the user form.  Thank you.